# Can you constructively prove a univariate polynomial algebra over a Jacobson ring is itself Jacobson?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, constructive-mathematics

Recall the Jacobson radical of a commutative ring $\mathrm J(A)=\lbrace a\in A\mid \forall b\in A:1-ba\in A^\times\rbrace$. The Jacobson radical of a quotient by an ideal $I\vartriangleleft A$ is therefore $\mathrm J(A/I) =\lbrace a+I\in A\mid \forall b\in A:1-ba\in (A/I)^\times\rbrace$. If I am unpacking correctly, $a+I\in \mathrm J(A/I)$ means $$\forall b\in A\exists c\in A:1-c(1-ba)\in I.$$

The nilradical of the quotient is $\mathrm{nil}(A/I)=\lbrace a+I\mid \exists n\in \mathbb N:a^n\in I \rbrace$. Hence, to prove $\mathrm J(A/I)\subset \mathrm{nil}(A/I)$ it suffices to prove:

$$[\forall b\in A\exists c\in A:1-c(1-ba)\in I]\implies a\in \sqrt I.$$

**Question 1.** How to *constructively* prove this implication for $A=R[x]$ (with $R$ a Jacobson ring) and, say, a non-radical principal ideal like $\langle x^n \rangle$?

When $R=\Bbbk$ is a field then I see how to prove the *contrapositive* for all sorts of ideals. For instance $a\notin \sqrt{\langle x^n\rangle} $ means $a\in \Bbbk[x]$ has a nonzero free coefficient, so letting $b\in \Bbbk$ be its inverse we find $1-ba\in \langle x\rangle$...

**Question 2.** How to prove (hopefully without prime ideals) the contrapositive for ideals $I\vartriangleleft R[x]$ involving irreducibles, or non-principal ideals?

Comment: You probably assume your ring commutative, else nilpotent elements have no reason to form an ideal. Is it what you mean?

Comment: @AurélienDjament yes. I have added this to the question body.

Comment: Dear @PaceNielsen I am interested in both. I have edited the question.

Comment: It seems to me that there might be issues with what "for every ideal $I$" means in the constructive world. For example, let $R$ be a field $k$ and let $I \subset k[x]$ be generated by $x^n$ for all even integers $n \geq 4$ which are not sums of two primes. Then, if the Goldbach conjecture is true, $I = (0)$ so $x$ is in neither the nil-radical nor the Jacobson radical of $k[x]/I$ but, if the Goldbach conjecture is false, then $x$ is in both the nil-radical and the Jacobson radical of $k[x]/I$. Do you allow this sort of shenanigans?

Comment: Dear @DavidESpeyer, I didn't consider such "pathologies". I am happy to restrict to ideals which we know to be finitely generated. What interests me is the "equational" approach.

Comment: You might not need the "for every ideal $I$" part. It seems that if the Jacobson radical of $R$ is the nilradical of $R$, then the same holds for $R\left[x\right]$. At least, I seem to conclude this from Lemmas 2J and 3J in [S. A. Amitsur, *Radicals of polynomial rings*, Canadian Journal of Mathematics, 8, 355--361, doi:10.4153/cjm-1956-040-9](https://doi.org/10.4153/cjm-1956-040-9). Am I misreading Amitsur? (This still doesn't answer the question for a constructive proof, but hopefully simplifies the question.)

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: how is your "shenanigans" limited to constructive mathematics? Your argument and example works equally well if excluded middle is assumed. Also, there is no question about what "for all ideals" means in the constructive world.

Comment: @darijgrinberg If $R$ is a commutative ring, then the Jacobson radical of $R[x]$ is equal to the nilradical of $R[x]$, whether or not the same is true for $R$.  This is a theorem of E. Snapper.  For a nice proof see  Theorem 5.1 in Lam's "First Course in Noncommutative Rings".

Comment: @Arrow How are you defining $R$ to be a *Jacobson ring* constructively?

Comment: By the way, a nonconstructive proof appears explicitly on pages 67--69 of T.Y. Lam's book "A First Course in Noncommutative Ring Theory" (among many other places).  This answers question #2, but the given proofs definitely use prime ideals.